# I want to get dynamic range of values of a column in a table which are not existent

Tags: sql, database, rows

I want to get dynamic range of values of a column in a table which are not existent.

Ex: Table: EMPLOYEE, Column: PAYPERIOD.

Employee table has Payperiod values ranging from 1,2,3,....,1000. (980 rows). There are 20 row values that are missing from 1 to 1000 and no values from 1001 onwards.

Now, I want to fetch the the dynamic (or) sequential ten values of Payperiod from Employee table which are not existing.

Comment: What is this question about? Are you asking about a spreadsheet, a database or a web page, or something else? Help us to help you.

Comment: Hi, it is about database. For suppose, if a table 'A', with column 'B' values 1.2.3. I want a query which can directly pull from the table 'A' which fetches the column values from 11 onwards which are nonexistent.

Comment: What database? Are you asking about an SQL query?

Comment: Yes Brian, want sql query.

Comment: maybe investigate LAG functions in your database to check if there is a 'gap' in the numbering